# How do I put 24 hour data on the x-axis ? MPAndroidChart, Android Studio

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I am developing a graph using Android MPAndroidChart.
It shows the DB with 24-hour data in 1 minute units as a graph.
I get data from DB well, but I don't know how to set the x-axis format.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPj9Q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usD5C.png)

Image 1 is the ideal graph I want, and image 2 is the actual graph.

my code is

```html
xAxis1.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));
tempChart.setData(data1);
tempChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
tempChart.invalidate();
```

In summary, it goes like this:
Because there is data every minute, is the x-axis value omitted because there are too many?
Or is there another way...;

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlT6z.png)

I put image 2 wrong.
As in this image, only half of the x-axis values come out.

Comment: Please share more details about the issue you are facing.

You can try including some `pseudocode` from your solution and possible alternatives you have tried